# How to detect if the project reference is existing project or dll itself?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide

I'm interested how can I determine within Visual Studio (possibly from a given project reference properties window) if a project reference was included as an existing project or targeted as a dll itself?
This becomes handy when there are unresolved reference that I have to remove and include again, so I could know what kind of reference to search for.

Comment: Look in the `.csproj` file.

Comment: thanks. is there anyway to see this from within Visual Studio?